# Coloring Rows Based On Conditions in Two Columns

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, vba

In Column B and Column C I have the values of `11`, `22` and `33` in various cells. I would like for the rows to be colored if `11`, `22` or `33` are in ANY row in either Column B or Column C.

I have tried Conditional Formatting but cannot get the formula to work correctly.

Either VBA or Conditional Formatting is fine.

Comment: Sorry we do not take request(s) here :) If you are facing some specific problem with the code then post that and the error message if any and then we will take it from there.

Comment: @pnuts: I asked that because the question is tagged with Excel-VBA so OP is looking for a VBA solution as well ;) As far as "efforts" are concerned in case of CF, I would like to see that as well. I want to see what formulas did OP try? Where is he stuck. etc..

Comment: @pnuts: You are most welcome to post an answer. It is after all a personal choice ;)

Comment: @pnuts: Like I mentioned in my last comment posting an answer is a personal choice. In such a case, you will not be stepping on anyone's toes :D

Answer (score 0):

Select the columns to be formatted and apply the following CF formula rule:

```
 =OR($B1=11,$B1=22,$B1=33,$C1=11,$C1=22,$C1=33)
```